# No Provider for CarouselComponent ngx-boostrap and angular 4 app

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to get ngx-bootstrap working angular 4.4.5 with angular-cli.
I have followed all the instructions, I have installed bootstrap 4.0.0-beta with all peer dependencies, and I have setup the project properly.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SwingModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    MultiselectDropdownModule,
    CarouselModule.forRoot() //tried also Ng2BootstrapModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FirstComponent,
    MyOwnComponent,
    YetAnotherComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      'provide': APP_INITIALIZER,
      'useFactory': LookupService.lookupServiceFactory,
      'deps': [LookupService],
      'multi': true
    },
    LookupService, PropertiesService, DefaultApi, CacheService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
  // Diagnostic only: inspect router configuration
  constructor(router: Router) {
    console.log('Routes: ', JSON.stringify(router.config, undefined, 2));
  }
}
```

I then try to use the component in the template of one of my custom components:

```
<div class="carousel card-image-top no-gutters">
    <ul class="slides">
      <slide *ngFor="let image of property.ads[0].images">
      <li>
        <img src="{{image}}" alt="">
      </li>
      </slide>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I tried to find various solutions for this, I tried all the github from valor-software, but all the solutions there didn't work.

I load I always get the same error.

```
PropertyViewerComponent.html:10 ERROR Error: No provider for CarouselComponent!
    at injectionError (core.es5.js:1169)
    at noProviderError (core.es5.js:1207)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (core.es5.js:2649)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (core.es5.js:2688)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (core.es5.js:2620)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.ReflectiveInjector_.get (core.es5.js:2489)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.es5.js:9492)
    at NgModuleRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.es5.js:10562)
    at resolveDep (core.es5.js:11050)
    at createClass (core.es5.js:10912)
```

Comment: Where do you inject CarouselComponent?

Comment: I didn't inject it, I just use a directive in one of my component templates.

Comment: @yurzui I just added the html for the template, hope this helps.

Comment: Your slides should be wrapped in <carousel> tag. Did you look at example? https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/carousel

Comment: Thanks that did it :) !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems my tag was incorrect. Thanks to @yurzui
Missing I was missing the carousel element.
Changing the html to do:

```
<carousel class="carousel card-image-top no-gutters">
    <ul class="slides">
      <slide *ngFor="let image of property.ads[0].images">
      <li>
        <img src="{{image}}" alt="">
      </li>
      </slide>
    </ul>
  </carousel>
```

Solved it.
This means when getting a component missing, please make sure you have the correct tags in the html code!